# Firebase Functions: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a Function in my Firebase Database, that creates/updates a combined property of two others, whenever they change.

The model is like this:

```
database/
  sessions/
    id/
      day = "1"
      room = "A100"
      day_room = "1_A100"
```

And my function so far:

```
exports.combineOnDayChange = functions.database
    .ref('/sessions/{sessionId}/day')
    .onWrite(event => {
        if (!event.data.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        const day = event.data.val();
        const room = event.data.ref.parent.child('room').data.val();

        console.log(`Day: ${day}, Room: ${room}`)

        return event.data.ref.parent.child("day_room").set(`${day}_${room}`)
    });

exports.combineOnRoomChange = functions.database
    .ref('/sessions/{sessionId}/room')
    .onWrite(event => {
        if (!event.data.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        const room = event.data.val();
        const day = event.data.ref.parent.child('day').data.val();

        console.log(`Day: ${day}, Room: ${room}`)

        return event.data.ref.parent.child("day_room").set(`${day}_${room}`)
    });
```

But it's throwing this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

I'm following the very first example in the Firebase Functions Get Started ([Add the makeUppercase() function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add_the_makeuppercase_function)) and this is what it does in order to reach the entity reference:

```
event.data.ref.parent
```

Am I using the `child()` function wrongly? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When Cloud Functions triggers your code, it passes in a snapshot of the data that triggered the change.

In your code:

```
exports.combineOnDayChange = functions.database
    .ref('/sessions/{sessionId}/day')
```

This means you `event.data` has the data for `/sessions/{sessionId}/day`. It does not contain any data from higher in the tree.

So when you call `event.data.ref.parent`, this points to a location in the database for which the data hasn't been loaded yet. If you want to load the additional data, you'll have to load it explicitly in your code:

```
exports.combineOnDayChange = functions.database
.ref('/sessions/{sessionId}/day')
.onWrite(event => {
    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    const day = event.data.val();
    const roomRef = event.data.ref.parent.child('room');
    return roomRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) { 
      const room = snapshot.val();

      console.log(`Day: ${day}, Room: ${room}`)

      return event.data.ref.parent.child("day_room").set(`${day}_${room}`)
    });
});
```

Alternatively, consider triggering higher in your tree `/sessions/{sessionId}`. Doing so means that you get all the necessary data in `event.data` already, and also means you only need a single function:

```
exports.updateSyntheticSessionProperties = functions.database
.ref('/sessions/{sessionId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return; // the session was deleted
    }

    const session = event.data.val();
    const day_room = `${session.day}_${session.room}`;
    if (day_room !== session.day_room) {
      return event.data.ref.parent.child("day_room").set(`${day}_${room}`)
    });
});
```